# Text centered around specified character

Tags: horizontal-alignment, center, glue

This might sound like a simple question, but how can I have text both right- and left-aligned, i.e. centered around a pre-defined middle character (preferably in textmode and without a table)?

This is what I am looking for, essentially:

```
                  Foo – Bar
            Foofoobar – Splat
Some other long entry – And we're done.
```

I have tried `tabto`, `\hfill` and a few other things, but nothing seems to work reliably. Any pointers?

Comment: What's wrong with using a `tabular`-like environment?

Comment: Well you will have to declare somehow how large the left part can get.  You could e.g. use `\makebox[3cm][r]{foo}`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with tables per se, but this seems like it should be doable without, given that it's only a few lines of text. @UlrikeFischer: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\makebox[0pt][r]{Foo} – \makebox[0pt][l]{Bar}

\makebox[0pt][r]{Foofoobar} – \makebox[0pt][l]{Splat}

\makebox[0pt][r]{Some other long enty} – \makebox[0pt][l]{And we're done.}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

a zero width box hides the different lengths of the texts.

Comment: Thanks, this looks exactly like what I had in mind. Great to know there's more than one way to skin a cat :-)

Answer (score 3):

For measuring the width of the left side you can put all the lines at the left into `\hbox`es nested within a `\vbox` in turn placed into a `\hphantom`. Then do an `\llap` with each line at the left:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\phantombox[2]{%
  \leavevmode\hphantom{\vbox{#1}}\llap{#2}%
}%

\begin{document}

\noindent text \hfill text \hfill text \hfill text

\hbox{\phantombox{\hbox{Foo}\hbox{Foofoobar}\hbox{Some other long enty}}{Foo} -- \hbox{Bar}}
\hbox{\phantombox{\hbox{Foo}\hbox{Foofppbar}\hbox{Some other long enty}}{Foofoobar} -- \hbox{Splat}}
\hbox{\phantombox{\hbox{Foo}\hbox{Foofppbar}\hbox{Some other long enty}}{Some other long enty} -- \hbox{And we're done.}}%
\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

This can be automatized:

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand\leftright[2]{%
  \ifvmode\else\par\fi
  \leftrightloop{#1}#1{}{}\relax#2{}{}\relax
}%
\@ifdefinable\leftrightloop{%
  \long\def\leftrightloop#1#2#3\relax#4#5\relax{%
    \ifcat$\detokenize{#3#5}$\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {\par}{%
      \ifcat$\detokenize{#3}$\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
      {%
        \hbox{\hphantom{\vbox{\hboxloop#1{}{}\relax}} -- \hbox{#4}}%
        \leftrightloop{#1}{}{}\relax#5\relax
      }{%
        \ifcat$\detokenize{#5}$\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
        {%
          \hbox{\hphantom{\vbox{\hboxloop#1{}{}\relax}}\llap{#2}}%
          \leftrightloop{#1}#3\relax{}{}\relax
        }{%
          \hbox{\hphantom{\vbox{\hboxloop#1{}{}\relax}}\llap{#2} -- \hbox{#4}}%
          \leftrightloop{#1}#3\relax#5\relax
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\hboxloop{%
  \long\def\hboxloop#1#2\relax{%
    \ifcat$\detokenize{#2}$\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {}{\hbox{#1}\hboxloop#2\relax}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent text \hfill text \hfill text \hfill text

\leftright{{Foo}{Foofoobar}{Some other long enty}}%
          {{Bar}{Splat}{And we're done.}}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you need this centered within the width of the text of the page/within the width of the surrounding vertical box:

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand\leftright[2]{%
  \ifvmode\else\par\fi
  \leftrightloop{#1}{#2}#1{}{}\relax#2{}{}\relax
}%
\@ifdefinable\leftrightloop{%
  \long\def\leftrightloop#1#2#3#4\relax#5#6\relax{%
    \ifcat$\detokenize{#4#6}$\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {\par}{%
      \ifcat$\detokenize{#4}$\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
      {%
        \hbox to\hsize{%
          \hss
          \hphantom{\vbox{\hboxloop#1{}{}\relax}} -- 
          \rlap{#5}%
          \hphantom{\vbox{\hboxloop#2{}{}\relax}}%
          \hss
        }%
        \leftrightloop{#1}{#2}{}{}\relax#6\relax
      }{%
        \ifcat$\detokenize{#6}$\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
        {%
          \hbox to\hsize{%
            \hss
            \hphantom{\vbox{\hboxloop#1{}{}\relax}}\llap{#3}
            \hphantom{--}
            \hphantom{\vbox{\hboxloop#2{}{}\relax}}%
            \hss
          }%
          \leftrightloop{#1}{#2}#4\relax{}{}\relax
        }{%
          \hbox to\hsize{%
            \hss
            \hphantom{\vbox{\hboxloop#1{}{}\relax}}\llap{#3} -- 
            \rlap{#5}%
            \hphantom{\vbox{\hboxloop#2{}{}\relax}}%
            \hss
          }%
          \leftrightloop{#1}{#2}#4\relax#6\relax
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\hboxloop{%
  \long\def\hboxloop#1#2\relax{%
    \ifcat$\detokenize{#2}$\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {}{\hbox{#1}\hboxloop#2\relax}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent text \hfill text \hfill text \hfill text

\leftright{{Foo}{Foofoobar}{Some other long enty}}%
          {{Bar}{Splat}{And we're done.}}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you wish the separating en-dash to be centered within the width of the text of the page/within the width of the surrounding vertical box:

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand\leftright[2]{%
  \ifvmode\else\par\fi
  \leftrightloop{#1#2}#1{}{}\relax#2{}{}\relax
}%
\@ifdefinable\leftrightloop{%
  \long\def\leftrightloop#1#2#3\relax#4#5\relax{%
    \ifcat$\detokenize{#3#5}$\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {\par}{%
      \ifcat$\detokenize{#3}$\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
      {%
        \hbox to\hsize{%
          \hss
          \hphantom{\vbox{\hboxloop#1{}{}\relax}} -- 
          \rlap{#4}%
          \hphantom{\vbox{\hboxloop#1{}{}\relax}}%
          \hss
        }%
        \leftrightloop{#1}{}{}\relax#5\relax
      }{%
        \ifcat$\detokenize{#5}$\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
        {%
          \hbox to\hsize{%
            \hss
            \hphantom{\vbox{\hboxloop#1{}{}\relax}}\llap{#2}%
            \hphantom{--}
            \hphantom{\vbox{\hboxloop#1{}{}\relax}}%
            \hss
          }%
          \leftrightloop{#1}#3\relax{}{}\relax
        }{%
          \hbox to\hsize{%
            \hss
            \hphantom{\vbox{\hboxloop#1{}{}\relax}}\llap{#2} -- 
            \rlap{#4}%
            \hphantom{\vbox{\hboxloop#1{}{}\relax}}%
            \hss
          }%
          \leftrightloop{#1}#3\relax#5\relax
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\hboxloop{%
  \long\def\hboxloop#1#2\relax{%
    \ifcat$\detokenize{#2}$\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {}{\hbox{#1}\hboxloop#2\relax}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent text \hfill text \hfill text \hfill text

\leftright{{Foo}{Foofoobar}{Some other long enty}}%
          {{Bar}{Splat}{And we're done.}}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

(updated the answer to provide a third solution to follow up on David C's comment)

Here are three additional possible solutions. The first uses a combination of `center` and `tabular` environments, and the second uses a single `longtable` environment; both solutions center the entire tabular-like material horizontally. The third solution also employs a `tabular` environment, but it centers the material on the en-dash.

The first two solutions generate the same output if they fit on one page and no page break is required. If your list of points and counterpoints is fairly long and if allowing a page break somewhere inside the list is permissible, the second solution may be preferable.

[image]

The `\hrule` directives are there to indicate the width of the text block.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable} % for 'longtable' environment
\usepackage{array}     % for 'w' column type
\usepackage{calc}      % for '\widthof' macro

\newlength\mylen % calculate column widths for third solution
\setlength\mylen{(\textwidth-\widthof{\space\textendash\space})/2}

\begin{document}
\hrule
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ r @{\space\textendash\space} l }
                  Foo & Bar \\
            Foofoobar & Splat \\
Some other long entry & And we're done.
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\hrule
\begin{longtable}{ r @{\space\textendash\space} l }
                  Foo & Bar \\
            Foofoobar & Splat \\
Some other long entry & And we're done.
\end{longtable}
\hrule
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ @{} w{r}{\mylen} @{\space\textendash\space} w{l}{\mylen} @{} }
                  Foo & Bar \\
            Foofoobar & Splat \\
Some other long entry & And we're done.
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

Comment: it's possible that's what the OP wanted, but not as I read it: I think the dash should be in the centre, whereas this is centering the entire block.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks for this. I've updated my answer to provide a third possible solution, which centers the material on the en-dashes. Let's see if the OP will provide more information as to what they need.

Comment: David is correct: I had mean for the dash to be in the center. That said, thanks a lot for your effort (and that of @DavidCarlisle), this gives me a lot of options to toy around with.