# Aligning text to have all spaces above each other

Tags: alignment

I have a list of authors, centered, listed one on each line and would like them to have aligned the space between first and last name. How can I do that?

[image: Names 1 per line centered]

Comment: Welcome to  TeX SX! Could you show use  what you've tried?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). One way to do that would be to use a `tabular` environment  with an `rl` alignment.

Comment: This question is very similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/634194/52406). So, you might have other ideas from the answers inthere.

Comment: I asked a somewhat similar question about a month ago: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631911/ You might find the answers helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on @PeterGrill's comment, you could try something like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}r@{~}>{\bfseries}l@{}}
Adam &Novak\\
Lukas &Kaufmann\\
Jiri &Lezak\\
Frantisek &Votrubec\\
Matej &Velky\\
Tomas &Petracek
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Take out the `>{\bfseries}`'s if you don't want bold. (In the image they looked bold so I copied that.)

Comment: Thank you very much! one more thing I want that centered on the page. What do I need to change to have it aligned in the center?

Comment: I have managed to solve it by simplifying it into \begin{tabular}{rl}, because it already is in \begin{center}

Answer (score 1):

Give the columns a fixed width:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill XX\dotfill X

\begin{center}
\bfseries
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  w{r}{0.4\textwidth}
  @{ }
  w{l}{0.4\textwidth}
  @{}
}
Adam      & Novak \\
Lukas     & Kaufmann \\
Jiri      & Lezak \\
Frantisek & Votrubec \\
Matej     & Velky \\
Tomas     & Petracek \\
Short     & Looooooooooooooong
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

The alternative proposal by frabjous

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}r@{~}>{\bfseries}l@{}}
Adam &Novak\\
Lukas &Kaufmann\\
Jiri &Lezak\\
Frantisek &Votrubec\\
Matej &Velky\\
Tomas &Petracek\\
Short     & Looooooooooooooong
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]